# How can I declare dictionary using both ObjectMapper and Realm object

Tags: realm, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using ObjectMapper for JSON parsing and Realm for persistence please help me how can I declare a dictionary so that it will comptiable with both Object Mapper and Realm.

```
 class UserInfo: Object,Mappable
{
var name:String?
var identifier:String?
var accountType:String?
var devices:[UserDevice]?
required init?(map: Map)
{

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map)
{
    name <- map["username"]
    identifier <- map["identifier"]
    accountType <- map["accountType"]
    devices <- map["devices"]
}
```

}

==========

```
class UserDevice:Object,Mappable
{
var deviceName:String?
var deviceType:String?
var deviceIdentifier:String?

required init?(map: Map)
{

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    deviceName <- map["name"]
    deviceType <- map["type"]
    deviceIdentifier <- map["identifier"]
}
}


 JSON :


 {
username = santhosh;
"identifier" = "IDJSDJSJS";
configstatus = SET;
configtype = DEFAULT;
"data_center" = "evs.idrive.com";
devices = {
    "Ankita\LKKKK" = {
        identifier = LJJDFDD;
        name = "Ankita iPAD";
        type = iPad;
    };
    "ARUN\LKKKHJH" = {
        identifier = LJJDFDFFD;
        name = "ARUN iPhone";
        type = ipHone;
    };

    accountStatus = 2;
    acctype = Test;
}
```

How can I declare user devices so that it will be compatible with both Realm and ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ObjectMapper extension for Realm](https://github.com/jakenberg/ObjectMapper-Realm) that allows you to handle Realm `List` properties.

In your code above, you're not defining your properties as ones Realm will recognize. You need to prefix `dynamic` for all primitive types and use the Realm `List` object for the array.

The ObjectMapper extension has sample code to show how to parse the `List` object, but it should look something like this:

```
class UserInfo: Object, Mappable
{
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var identifier: String?
    dynamic var accountType: String?
    let devices = List<UserDevice>()

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name       <- map["username"]
        identifier <- map["identifier"]
        accountType <- map["accountType"]
        devices    <- (map["devices"], ListTransform<User>())
    }
}

class UserDevice: Object, Mappable
{
    dynamic var deviceName: String?
    dynamic var deviceType: String?
    dynamic var deviceIdentifier: String?
}
```

Comment: thanks for the "dynamic" keyword. I am using it but i forgot put paste that code. I have tried your approach it doest not work because if we declare devices as  let devices = List<UserDevice>() Object mapper does not recognise them becuase they are coming as array of dictionaries .

Comment: One more thing if i am trying mark  dynamic var userDevices: List<UserDevice>?  getting an error "Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C" . ObjectMapper understands the way it stays in JSON.

Comment: I should declare devices as  let devices = [String:UserDevice] so that JSON can be understood by ObjectMapper, otherwise Objectmapper is returning nil always

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Yeah, Realm `List` objects aren't Objective-C, so they don't need the `dynamic` keyword. If you change it to `[String:UserDevice]`, it won't get saved in Realm.

Comment: hmm I can't declare the object as [String:UserDevice]